# Mysql Query Statistics

Tags: python, mysql, performance, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

The Following are some query statistics I use to get form workbench. I am looking for a automation. I am writing a python script that can execute the query and give its stats. I used profiling (deprecated now). How to get all these stats data when a query is given ?

```
Query Execution Time :
Execution time: 0:00:0.00824800
Table lock wait time: 0:00:0.00021400

Temporary Tables :
Temporary disk tables created: 1
Temporary tables created: 1

Join per type :
Full table scans (Select_scan): 1
Joins using table scans (Select_full_join): 0
Joins using range search (Select_full_range_join): 1
Joins with range checks (Select_range_check): 0
Joins using range (Select_range): 0

Sorting :
Sorted rows (Sort_rows): 0
Sort merge passes (Sort_merge_passes): 0
Sorts with ranges (Sort_range): 0
Sorts with table scans (Sort_scan): 0
```

Please suggest a performance and stats measuring framework/ tool that I can use with python or java.

Answer (score 1):

- `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`  (Tip:  This lets you know which step needs "filesort", and whether multiple steps need it.)
- `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`  (only in very recent versions)
- Optimizer trace.
- Slowlog has some info.  Recommend `pt-query-digest` for summarizing it.  (Tip:  Best for finding which query is "worst".)
- General log has some info.  (Tip: Use with caution; it writes lots to disk.)
- Either of the above logs can be written to a `TABLE`, but there might not be as much info as with `FILE`.
- `performance_schema`
- I use this technique primarily for "Handler" counts, but other things are available:

  ```
    FLUSH STATUS;
    run the query
    SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
  ```
- For things that are not session specific, such as most `Innodb_% status values, use the following.  Afterward, subtract the second output from the first.

  ```
    SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
    run the query
    SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
  ```
- Caution:  `Sort_merge_passes`, though session-specific, continues to increment.

When I am called in for performance help, I start with these:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

('Profile' rarely showed anything other than 99% of the time was in one of about 3 states, such as the cryptic "Sending data".  I'm glad it is going away.)

Comment: Any Idea on how to integrate it with python? I use mysql 5.6. Let us say I have a select query. I need to get this statistics in python.

Comment: @INDIANDECODER - The status values are available in `information_schema.SESSION_STATUS` via ordinary `SELECT` statements.

Comment: @INDIANDECODER - Running `SHOW` works like running `SELECT`.